# Appending "in a way" multiple matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I have matrices A and B. I want to create a third matrix C where

```
A = [1,0,0,1]

B = [1,0,1,0]    

C = [11, 00, 01, 10]
```

Is there such a function in Matlab? If not how would I go about creating a function that does this?

Edit: C is not literal numbers. They are concatenated values of A,B element-wise.

Edit2: The actual problem I am dealing with is I have 10 large matrices of the size [x,y] where x,y > 1000. The elements in these matrices all have 0s and 1s. No other number. What I need to accomplish is have the element [x1,y1] in matrix 1 to be appended to the element in [x1,y1] of matrix 2. and then that value to be appended to [x1,y1] of matrix 3.

Another example:

```
A = [1,1,1,1;
     0,0,0,0]

B = [0,0,0,0;
     1,1,1,1]

C = [1,0,1,0;
     0,1,0,1]
```

And I need a matrix D where

```
D = [101, 100, 101, 101; 010, 011, 010, 011]
```

Comment: By `C = [11, 00, 01, 10]` do you literally mean `eleven, zero, one, ten` or do you mean something else?  Are you trying to perform binary operations?

Comment: Trying to perform binary operations, but I have multiple matrices of 0s and 1s. C is not literally the number, but binary numbers. But I'd like to concatenate A and B element-wise.

Comment: I thought that looked too easy.  :)  So are these strings?  How would it look in MATLAB?

Comment: Ah, I guess I never realized that it can't really look that way in the elements of matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you want the output formatted.  You could apply `bitshift` to the numerical values and convert to binary:

```
>> b = dec2bin(bitshift(A,1)+B)

b =

    11
    00
    01
    10
```

For a general matrix `Digits`:

```
>> Digits

Digits =

     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1

>> Ddec = D*(2.^(size(D,2)-1:-1:0))'; % dot product
>> dec2bin(Ddec)

ans =

1000
0100
1011
1100
1000
1011
1100
1010
0111
0111
```

Another way to write that is `dec2bin(sum(D .* repmat(2.^(size(D,2)-1:-1:0),size(D,1),1),2))`.

For your larger problem, with 10 large matrixes (say `M1`, `M2`, ..., `M10`), you can build the starting `Digits` matrix by:

```
Digits = [M1(:) M2(:) M3(:) M4(:) M5(:) M6(:) M7(:) M8(:) M9(:) M10(:)];
```

If that is reverse the order of the digits, just do `Digits = fliplr(Digits);`.

If you would rather not reshape anything you can compute the matrix decimal values from the matrices of digits as follows:

```
M = cat(3,A,B,C);
Ddec = sum(bsxfun(@times,M,permute(2.^(size(M,3)-1:-1:0),[1 3 2])),3)
```

Comment: Ah! I believe that second part does what I'm looking for, thanks very much!

Comment: Darn, this method messes up once there are more rows and columns involved. Happen to have a quick fix where it'll do a num2str concatenate when there are multiple columns, rows?

Comment: @Phirip - How do you want to address the variable naming scheme?  It would probably best to have a matrix where the number of columns are the multiple digits (0s an 1s), and the number of rows are the different numbers you want to assemble.  For example, `D = randi(2,10,4)-1` How about that?

Comment: Let me just say thanks so much for the help @chappjc, I really appreciate it! This isn't quite what I'm looking for, but I'll keep truckin to find a solution that's right for my problem.

Comment: I believe I won't be able to retain the order. it's a 1224x1632 matrix, and if I do the Digits, it won't map to the same coordinates right? I'll be able to get the binaries, and then convert them, but how will I get back a 1224x1632 matrix with the correct decimals?

Comment: The order is retained when doing `M1(:)`.  Just `reshape` the computed decimal values back to 1224x1632 and they will be were they started. That is, build `Digits` like in the updated answer, compute `Ddec` and `reshape(Ddec,size(M1))`.

Comment: @Phirip You could also do what I suggested in my answer with bitshift.  In this case, there is no reshaping necessary, and the matrices always retain their size.

Comment: Is there a way to do calculations now on (ans) in the above? I think (ans) becomes a char, and then I'm not sure how I'll be able to convert these binaries to, well, other binaries with a gray2bi function I have.

Comment: @Phirip - Added a version at the end that does not do any reshaping, and gives the decimal representations in a matrix of the same size as input.  Just extend the `cat(3,...)` command to bring in all of your matrices.  This was fun! :)

Comment: @Phirip What you do with the string representations is a different question.  This was nispio's point, that it is safer to stay in a numerical format until you absolutely need to display something's binary representation.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you **avoid manipulating binary numbers as strings** where possible.  It seems tempting, and there are cases where matlab provides a more elegant solution if you treat a binary number as a string, but *you cannot perform binary arithmetic on strings*. You can always work with integers as if they were binary (they are stored as bits in your machine after all), and then just *display them* as binary numbers using `dec2bin` when necessary.

```
A = [1,0,0,1]
B = [1,0,1,0]
C = bitshift(A,1)+B;
display(dec2bin(C));
```

In the other case you show in your question you could use:

```
A = [1,1,1,1; 0,0,0,0];
B = [0,0,0,0; 1,1,1,1];
C = [1,0,1,0; 0,1,0,1];
D = bitshift(A,2) + bitshift(B,1) + C;
```

You can also convert an arbitrary length row vector of zeros and ones into its decimal equivalent by defining this simple function:

```
mat2dec = @(x) x*2.^(size(x,2)-1:-1:0)';
```

This will also work for matrices too. For example

```
>> M = [0 0 1; 0 1 1; 0 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 1 1; 1 1 0; 1 0 0];
>> dec2bin(mat2dec(M))

ans =

001
011
010
110
111
110
100
```

In my experience, treating binary numbers as strings obfuscates your code and is not very flexible. For example, try adding two binary "strings" together. You have to use `bin2dec` every time, so why not just leave the numbers as numbers until you want to display them? You have already run into some of the issues caused by strings of different lengths too. You will be amazed how one simple change can break everything when treating numbers as strings.  The worst part is that an algorithm may work great for one set of data and not for another.  If all I test with is two-bit binary numbers and a three-bit number somehow sneaks its way in, I may not see an error, but my results will be inexplicably incorrect. I realize that this is a very subjective issue, and I think that I definitely stand in the minority on StackOverflow, so take it for what it's worth.

Comment: That's probably excellent advise. I just don't know another way of doing the problem if I don't have the binary number easily usable. What I'll ultimately be set out to do is I have these binary numbers which are actually GrayCode numbers. I will need to take those numbers and convert those to Binary numbers. Then binary numbers to Decimal (which is the easiest part). Getting to GrayCode to Binary from the multiple matrices is what is stumping me!

Comment: Agreed.  This is why I ended with `dec2bin` in my example -- to demonstrate the meaning of the digits.  It's best just to work in numbers.  @Phirip - I added a gernal solution to any number of digits.

Comment: I recommend you start a new question that addresses specific issues you are having with Gray Code.

Answer (score 0):

I see some quite extensive answers so perhaps this is thinking too simple, but how about just this assuming you have vectors of ones and zeros representing your binary numbers:

```
A = [1,0,0,1];
B = [1,0,1,0];  

C = 10*A + B
```

This should give you the numbers you want, you may want to add leading zeros. Of course this method can easily be expanded to append multiple matrices, you just need to make sure there is a factor (base) 10 between them before adding.

Comment: See my very first edit on my answer.  It was kind of a joke, but before the question was clarified and expanded it certainly answered the question.